# Converting Excel 2.0 files into a newer format

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xlrd

I would like to convert lots of Excel 2.0 (from 1988) files into a newer Excel format (min. Excel 97) but I can't really figure out how to do. Unfortunately Apache POI only supports Excel 8.0+. Converting into another format may be an option, but I would like to stick to Excel.

Comment: Did you try using Apache OpenOffice / LibreOffice? You can script/batch that

Comment: Possibilities: (1) On a Windows machine, you should be able to script to open each old file and "save as" (2) use xlrd to read each old file and xlwt to write the contents to an 8.0 xls file however you'd lose the formulas.

Comment: For option 1, you would need to be scripting an instance of Excel 2003 aka 8.0. Excel 2007 and later don't support saving as Excel 2.1 to 4.0 inclusive. Are you sure your files are 2.0 and not 2.1?